# Create and serve a file in Golang without saving it to the disk

Tags: web-services, go

I want to use the data provided by the client to serve a file for them to download (say .txt) without creating or persisting any files on my server. How can I do it?

For instance, I want to omit the `os.Create()` `defer f.Close()` part from the following code with `Gin` framework:

```
func serveFile(c *gin.Context) {
    
    path := "/tmp/hello.txt"
    f, _ := os.Create(path)
    defer f.Close()

    f.WriteString("hello world")
    f.Sync()

    // ...
    c.File(path)
}
```

Answer (score 3):

After setting proper response headers eg

```
w.Header().Set("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=hello.txt")
w.Header().Set("Content-Type", r.Header.Get("Content-Type"))
```

you can

```
w.Write("hello world")
```

you can also use http.ServeContent

https://cs.opensource.google/go/go/+/refs/tags/go1.17.1:src/net/http/fs.go;l=192v

Comment: Thank you for this. I just saw this in my networking course, and now I know why this works!

Answer (score 1):

Use [c.Data()](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/gin-gonic/gin#Context.Data) to write a string to the response:

```
c.Data(http.StatusOK, "text/plain", []byte("hello world"))
```